# Adding quotes around a field, except for null, using sed

Tags: mysql, linux, sed

I'm using mysql client to export the records of a table into a CSV file. Everything works fine, except when the records have null fields.

```
mysql --execute="SELECT * FROM users"| sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;' > users.csv
```

Produces

```
"John","Smith","john@smith.com","NULL","NULL","347-1234566"
```

How can I produce a result like this, where the NULL values are added to the file without the quotes around

```
"John","Smith","john@smith.com",NULL,NULL,"347-1234566"
```

Comment: Normally MySQL emits `\N` for NULL values, a non-standard CSVism. In terms of CSV, though, there's literally no difference between `"NULL"` and `NULL` since both are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mysql --execute="SELECT * FROM users"| sed 's/\t/","/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/"NULL"/NULL/g' > users.csv
```

The only change to your command is the addition of `s/"NULL"/NULL/g`.

If `sed` supported look-ahead or look-behind regex features, there might be more complex ways of doing this, but it doesn't have such features.

#### Example

With this tab-separated file as sample input:

```
$ cat file
John    Smith   john@smith.com  NULL    NULL    347-1234566
```

You can achieve the output that you want with:

```
$ sed 's/\t/","/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/"NULL"/NULL/g' file
"John","Smith","john@smith.com",NULL,NULL,"347-1234566 "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
John    Smith   john@smith.com  NULL    NULL    347-1234566
```

A bit of regex magic, courtesy [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

```
$ perl -lpe 'tr /\t/,/; s/NULL(*SKIP)(*F)|([^,]+)/"$1"/g' ip.txt 
"John","Smith","john@smith.com",NULL,NULL,"347-1234566"
```

- `tr /\t/,/` replace all tabs with comma. This makes the substitution easier
- `NULL(*SKIP)(*F)` to ignore this pattern
- `([^,]+)` capture one or more non-comma characters
- `"$1"` surround the captured string with double quotes

Alternate way, using `map` to transform each element

```
$ perl -lane 'print join ",", map{ /^NULL$/ ? $_ : "\"$_\"" } @F' ip.txt
"John","Smith","john@smith.com",NULL,NULL,"347-1234566"
```